# RabbitMQ caching results?

Tags: python, urllib2, rabbitmq

If I try to query a queue from our `RabbitMQ` server via `REST` I always get cached results. Meaning if I execute the following code, I get the same result twice allthough the queue has already changed. Maybe this also `urllib2` related.

```
url = "https://someip:55672/api/queues/%2f/some_queue"
passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, RMQ_USERNAME, RMQ_PASSWORD)
authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
pagehandle = urllib2.urlopen(url)
result = pagehandle.read()
```

How can I always obtain the realtime result?

Comment: Er, wouldn't this depend on the code of the REST service itself, rather than how you're calling it?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your service puts cacheable flags in http response header?
Please use curl -v or tcpdump to verify http headers.